# Remove White Background from Png in Flutter Image

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this bit of code that shows image (or imagepath if saved) in DecorationImage, but the issue is that the transparent png transparency is seen as white background (the _logo is a **File**) Here's the code:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
           image: _logopath != null
              ? FileImage(File(_logopath))
                : _logo == null
                 ? MemoryImage(kTransparentImage)
                  : FileImage(_logo),
                   fit: BoxFit.contain),
```

My question is if there is some way for the png image selected to be actually transparent as it is, and without the white background filling transparency.

Comment: I have the same issue ,the answer below is not correct ,  we still need a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's already transparent.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  image: AssetImage('images/gyvegetable.png'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: sample]